# one-time binding with not operator

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

```
<div ng-if="::showError"> <!-- working as expected -->

<div ng-if="::!showError"> <!-- not working as expected -->
```

The bottom expression is always true, even when showError = true. Without the single binding it is working as expected. How should the single binding be used with the not operator?

Comment: Does enclosing it in round brackets `( )`work?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the expression is not first evaluated with `showError = false`?

I tried this syntax and it works for me, see the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQiBpdsTMrHEfomMnTv8?p=preview)

The text is initially set to any value. Hence on the first pass, the expression `::!text` will evaluate to `false`. Clearing the textbox afterwards does not cause the expression to reevaluate, as expected.

Comment: jep, showError is only set once. Must be an other issue than

Comment: Strange, I upfatedthe punker to make use of an `ng-if` binding and it's stil working for me. What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Version 1.3. ShowError is used in an ng-if to show either loading text (when it's undefined), or the actual content. I found a difference between using brackets () in the ng-if expression but still no final solution which worked in all cases  I had in mind. Could also be a preprocessing issue (I'm using jade)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this updated [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hnAioQ6pQFtjAgNmB1oX?p=preview)

play arround with

```
showError = false


showError = true
```